# Not able to insert date using CREATED in cakephp1.3

Tags: cakephp-1.3

HI I am stuck here and any immediate help will be appreciated.I am trying to use the created function in cakephp 1.3 so that the "asked question" date is automatically inserted. Name of the field in DB is "created" ,datatype :date and Default is set to NULL. 
The entry is inserted in the table using following steps.

1) This step calls the ask_question function defined in Askquestion model.

```
        $question['Askquestion']['user_id']=$user_id;
        $question['Askquestion']['subject_id']=$_POST['subject_id'];
        $question['Askquestion']['topic_id']=$_POST['topic_id'];        
        $question['Askquestion']['subject']=$_POST['subject_name'];
        $question['Askquestion']['topic']=$_POST['topic_name'];             
        $question['Askquestion']['question']=$_POST['content'];
        App::import("model","Askquestion");
        $this->Askquestion = new Askquestion();
        $this->Askquestion->ask_question($question);
```

2) In ask_question function in Model

function ask_question($data=array()){
        $db=$this->getDataSource();

```
    $askquestion['Askquestion']['user_id']=$data['Askquestion']['user_id'];
    $askquestion['Askquestion']['subject_id']=$data['Askquestion']['subject_id'];
    $askquestion['Askquestion']['topic_id']=$data['Askquestion']['topic_id'];
    $askquestion['Askquestion']['subject']=$data['Askquestion']['subject'];
    $askquestion['Askquestion']['topic']=$data['Askquestion']['topic'];
    $askquestion['Askquestion']['question']=$data['Askquestion']['question'];


    $this->create();
    $this->save($askquestion);
    return $this->getLastInsertId();
}
```

When i check the DB all other fields have corresponding value however the created field has NULL in it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the type needs to be datetime, not date: http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Models.html#created-and-modified.